# Pandas DatetimeIndex format using Styler

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, pandas-styles

When I have a dataframe that's displayed without using a `Styler`, the `DatetimeIndex` displays in the way I want:

```
In [1]: df
```

[image]

However, when I try to apply a style for the dataframe display, the `DatetimeIndex` transforms into something I don't like:

```
In [2]: df.style\
            .format({'volatility_5': '{:.1}'})\
            .bar(subset=['volatility_5'])
```

[image]

How do I make the `DatetimeIndex` display `YYYY-MM-DD` format again?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is convert `DatetimeIndex` to `string`s:

```
level0 = df.index.get_level_values(0)
level1 = df.index.get_level_values(1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level0, level1], names=df.index.names)
df = df.set_index(mux) \
       .style\
       .format({'volatility_5': '{:.1}'})\
       .bar(subset=['volatility_5'])
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'volatility_5': np.arange(5) * 10.293, 'ticker':['TBGI'] * 5}).set_index(['ticker','date'])
level0 = df.index.get_level_values(0)
level1 = df.index.get_level_values(1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level0, level1], names=df.index.names)
df = df.set_index(mux) \
       .style\
       .format({'volatility_5': '{:.1}'})\
       .bar(subset=['volatility_5'])
```

[image: pic]